# Discriminate double that has no value and double that is 0 in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Good day to you all.

I have a little question regarding VBA, and variable initialization:

I have a class, with property

```
Public myVal As Double
```

The two scripts:

```
Dim myObject As new MyClass
myObject.myClass = 0
Debug.Print myObject.myClass

Dim myObject As new MyClass
Debug.Print myObject.myClass
```

give the same output: 0.

Is there any way to tell the two zeroes (Value has been assigned to 0 - No value has been assigned, so output is 0 by default) apart?

Side question:
If I declared as

```
Public myVal As Variant
```

I have no problem, as I can use IsEmpty(myClass.myVal).

Since people usually prefer using Double over Variant, I guess there is a downside to it. What is it?

Thanks for your help :)

Maxime

Comment: Variant is usually not preferred because it uses extra memory, can require a pointer dereference, and can carry unexpected types that cause runtime errors. However, it definitely has the advantage of being tested for uninitialized values. A typical approach to this sort of problem in programming is to simple initialize your data to a program-defined "illegal value" like -1, then check against this condition. But this obviously doesn't work if your Double could be legally assigned any value, including -1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The downside has nothing to do with making the variable a `Double` or a `Variant`.  It has to do with exposing the guts of your class to anything that wants to muck around in them.

I'd recommend creating actual properties and using those to report on the state of your object.  This line...

```
Public myVal As Double
```

...does **not** make `myVal` a property of the class.  It gives it a public internal member variable and breaks [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).  Make it an actual property instead.  That way, you can have other properties that report the object's state if needed:

**MyClass.cls:**

```
Option Explicit

Private mInit As Boolean
Private mVal As Double

Public Property Get DoubleValue() As Double
    DoubleValue = mVal
End Property

Public Property Let DoubleValue(inValue As Double)
    mInit = True
    mVal = inValue
End Property

Public Property Get Initialized() As Boolean
    Initialized = mInit
End Property
```

**Calling code:**

```
Dim myObject As New MyClass
myObject.DoubleValue = 0
Debug.Print myObject.DoubleValue        '0
Debug.Print myObject.Initialized        'True

Dim myOtherObject As New MyClass
Debug.Print myOtherObject.DoubleValue   '0
Debug.Print myOtherObject.Initialized   'False
```